# Alternative for 'set @myvariable = value' in Mysql for Postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm now using Postgresql and used to Mysql...
I'm searching for the alternative of setting value to a variable.

What I found is that the difference is '@' and in Postgresql we have to call a function to set values to variables. I tested this one :

```
SET SESSION "variable_session.top" = value;
SELECT current_setting('variable_session.top') AS "myvariable";
```

But when i'm trying to do an affectation for this variable i'm getting an error :

```
select column from table where variable2 :myvariable;
```

Syntax error ":"...

Can you help me please ?

Thank you..

NB : i know that in cmd line we can use \set myvariable value but it's a script not a simple command line

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is :

```
set session.myvariable = value;
```

then you can do this :

```
select * from table where column = current_setting(session.myvariable);
```

You can need to specify the type of the variable like this :

```
select * from table where column = current_setting(session.myvariable)::integer;
```